# Add markers from an arraylist of latlng

Tags: android, arraylist, markers

```
public class Viewmap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnMarkerClickListener {

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();




        ArrayList<LatLng> Points;
        // url to get all products list
        private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.254.107/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
        private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";
    GoogleMap googleMap;


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmap);

     // Hashmap for ListView

            Points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();




        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        // Getting Google Play availability status

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

             // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

            new LoadAllProducts().execute();





         // Loading products in Background Thread


        }
    }







    private void DrawMarker(LatLng point){
        String add = "";
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Viewmap.this,
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude,
                    point.longitude, 1);
            add = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "," + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + "," + 
                    addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2)+","+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3);

            }

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            // Adding marker on the Google Map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions
                    .title("Click here to do desired action")
                    .snippet(add));


    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Viewmap.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();


        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                        try {
                            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // products found
                                // Getting Array of Products
                                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                                // looping through All Products
                                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                    String LAT = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                                    String LNG = c.getString(TAG_LNG);

                                    double lat = Double.valueOf(LAT);
                                    double lng = Double.valueOf(LNG);              


                                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);



                                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    Points.add(position);
                                }
                            } else {
                                // no products found
                                // Launch Add New product Activity
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                        NewProductActivity.class);
                                // Closing all previous activities
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        PolylineOptions opt = new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(Points)
                        .color(Color.RED);

                    // Add the new line. Keep track of the added polylines
                    // in a list.
                    Polyline p = googleMap.addPolyline(opt);



                    }

                }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {




        return false;
    }
}
```

After placing all the latitude and longitude from my database to arraylist of LatLng points , i want to draw all the markers stored in the arraylist of LatLng to the OnPostExecute and i cant seem to find any answers.

Comment: what problem you are getting using current code

Comment: im not having any problems with these codes i just want to draw all the markers using the stored lat and lng in the arraylist .. i cant seem to find any examples regarding with that matter..

Comment: can you add a code in the onPostExecute  where I can add markers from the arraylist of latlng , or do i need to use loop in the postexecute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can not get your question what exactly you want but if you just want to draw those LatLngs on map then Iterate through ArrayList of LatLng named points and call your method DrawMarker for every LatLng.

Comment: in doinbackground i am getting all the lat and lng values from my database and store it in an arraylist, onpostexecute the lat and lng stored in the arraylist will be drawn on the map .. can you provide some codes adding markers from points stored in an arraylist

Comment: that is the problem i cant seem to know how i will use those together with the arraylist.. i just want to add markers for every latlng stored in the arraylist of LATLNG in the onPostExecute can you provide me a sample code?

Comment: In postExecute method, write this code: 
if(Points.size>0) {
    for(LatLng point: Points) {
     DrawMarker(point);
    }
}